# How to fix "Tried to register two views with the same name RNGestureHandlerButton" in ReactNative?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I wanted to add a **Swipe-to-Delete** effect to my App and I've manually installed the **react-native-gesture-handler**. Since then I get an error message...I have already tried to uninstall the manually installed gesture handler without success. Any advice?

This is the code from my component where I tried to test the gesture handler. Since then I only get the red screen with the above-mentioned warning and can't do anything anymore. 
Sorry, I'm a beginner.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {Image, StyleSheet, TouchableHighlight, View, Text} from "react-native";
import Swipeable from "react-native-gesture-handler/Swipeable";

renderLeftActions = (progress, dragX) => {
  const trans = dragX.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 50, 100, 101],
    outputRange: [-20, 0, 0, 1]
  });
  return (
    <RectButton style={styles.leftAction} onPress={this.close}>
      <Animated.Text
        style={[
          styles.actionText,
          {
            transform: [{ translateX: trans }]
          }
        ]}
      />
    </RectButton>
  );
};

getAllToppings = toppings => {
  return toppings.map(topping => (
    <Swipeable renderLeftActions={this.renderLeftActions}>
      <Text style={styles.toppings}>{topping}</Text>
    </Swipeable>
  ));
};

render() {
  const menuDish = this.props.navigation.getParam('menuDish');
  let toppings = [];
  for (let key in menuDish.toppings) {
    toppings.push(menuDish.toppings[key])
  }
  return(
    <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <Image
            source={{url: menuDish.image}}
            style={styles.image}
        />
        <Text style={styles.dishName}>{menuDish.name}</Text>
        {this.getAllToppings(toppings)}
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: Please share with us your code - what you have tried so far.

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: No..not until now..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you share your package.json?

Anyway, try deleting the package.json / yarn.lock file and the node_modules folder and install them again.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this error by upgrading my `react-native-gesture-handler` dependency (at the time, from `1.0.14` to `1.0.17`).

Answer (score 0):

Check `react-native-gesture-handler` versions in your `yarn.lock` or `package-lock.json` and if there are different versions then try to update and make it point to only one particular version, probably by updating to latest.